# CamelContext is shutting down while initializing the PooledConnectionFactory

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, connection-pooling, wildfly-10

I'm trying to initialise the `ActiveMQComponent` using `org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactor` via camel cdi.
With the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`, this is working fine.

I added some logs also and noted that when the `PooledConnectionFactory`, `CamelContext` is getting shut down. When it is building and deploying
I tried many different ways with `JMSConfigurations` etc etc. But still no any luck.

What could be the reason for this?

**Error log.**

```
17:45:07,043 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-6) Apache Camel 2.19.3 (CamelContext: camel_cdi_context) is starting
17:45:07,044 INFO  [org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy] (MSC service thread 1-6) JMX is enabled
17:45:07,064 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.camel] (MSC service thread 1-6) Camel context starting: camel_cdi_context
17:45:07,064 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.camel] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bound camel naming object: java:jboss/camel/context/camel_cdi_context
17:45:07,095 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
17:45:07,131 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-6) Creating ActiveMQ Component
17:45:07,131 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-6) createActiveMQComponent().connectionFactory : org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory@6e871efa
17:45:07,131 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-6) createActiveMQComponent(). : mark-1
17:45:07,135 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-6) Apache Camel 2.19.3 (CamelContext: camel_cdi_context) is shutting down
17:45:07,137 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.camel] (MSC service thread 1-6) Camel context stopped: camel_cdi_context
```

I can proceed with the ActiveMQConnectionFactory and work on maximumConnections / timeouts in different ways. 
But I like to have the best.

**ActiveMQComponentProducer.java**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ActiveMQComponentProducer {

    @Produces
    @Named("activemqx")
    public ActiveMQComponent createActiveMQComponent() {

        System.out.println("Creating ActiveMQ Component");

        ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent();
        String connectionString = "tcp://localhost:61616";

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(connectionString);
        System.out.println("createActiveMQComponent().connectionFactory : " + connectionFactory);

        PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = null;
        System.out.println("createActiveMQComponent(). : mark-1");

        try {
            pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("createActiveMQComponent(). : "+e);
        }
        System.out.println("createActiveMQComponent(). : mark-2");

        activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory);
        return activeMQComponent;
    }

}
```

- Camel version : 2.19
- Wildfly version : 10.1.0
- Camel Patch Version :wildfly-camel-patch-4.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you're running into a class loading issue.

In the WildFly-Camel 4.9.0 release, `PooledConnectionFactory` is not automatically exported onto the deployment class path. This problem is fixed in future releases and was tracked by this issue:

https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel/issues/2199

As a workaround, you can add a module dependency for `org.apache.activemq` to your deployment via a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` descriptor. Place it within `META-INF` for JAR deployments or `WEB-INF` for a WAR deployment.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.activemq" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```